# Mensaje de notificación

Tags: html, c#, mvc

Quiero que al dar de alta o editar un dato me aparezca un mensaje de que se creó/editó correctamente. Esto es lo que estoy haciendo pero no me funciona, el mensaje del controlador no le llega al del Index, le llega null:

Acá se muestra el mensaje:

```
 
    @if (ViewBag.Alert != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                &times;
            </button>
            <strong>Aviso!</strong> @ViewBag.Alert
        </div>
    }
```

```
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Alert = "Se editó el Módulo correctamente";
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
```

No sé qué más mostrarles.

Comment: Borraste la pregunta anterior y creaste una nueva? En MVC, cuando estás haciendo redirección, para que los datos sobrevivan, debes usar `TempData` en lugar de `ViewBag`.

Comment: Sí, la borré porque como mencionó un usuario, era muy general la pregunta, ahora con el TempData funciona, gracias.